# Dealing with third party api rate limit when using multiple services

Tags: design, microservices, web-services, distributed-system, rate-limiting

I have 1 api key that has a rate limit 1000req/1min.

I would like to somehow use 50% of that limit in service 1 and 50% of that limit in service 2.  Let's say they're just 2 separate processes using the same api key. How could I implement distributed rate limiter like that?

https://www.jeremydaly.com/throttling-third-party-api-calls-with-aws-lambda/

Comment: Why not just throttle each service so that on average each one sends no more than 500 per minute? A simple `Thread.sleep(...)` in between requests is a good place to start.

Comment: That was my initial thought just asked this because wasn't sure if I'm on the right track of approaching this problem. Ty.

Comment: It really depends if you will always have 2 services or if you dynamically spin services based on demand.  If this simple approach doesn't work in practice, you may need to set up a queue and have a single service that pops off the queue to make those requests at the correct rate.